# JS Pattern matching from 2 different sources of data

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I have 2 tables (which can increase in future) with rows like

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bb</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aab</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aabb</td>
    <td>28</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>salary</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ac</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dc</td>
    <td>34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>acdc</td>
    <td>36</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cdcc</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think this can be done with JSON (with key being name and salary being value) but how can i achieve this is an issue.

I will put a value in the searchbox. I expect my program/script to show the salary according to the longest posible value entered with data fetched from both tables. For e.g when in enter just a,it should show 12 but when i enter ac, it should show 22 and acdc=36 and so on. Any example in JS/React/Angular is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should add HTML:

```
<input id="nameInput">
```

In clear js I'd write it like this:

```
const arr1 = [{ name: 'a', salary: 12 }, { name: 'bb', 'salary': 24 }];
const arr2 = [{ name: 'ac', salary: 22 }, { name: 'dc', 'salary': 34 }];

document.getElementById("nameInput").addEventListener(function() {
  // depending on what you want, you can change condition or function
  const foundValue = [ ...arr1, ...arr2].find(el => {
    return el === this.value;
  });

  // here you can do whatever you want with found value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are fetching data from two tables and having stored in two arrays.

```
let table1Data = [ {name: 'a', salary: 50}, {name: 'bc', salary: 45} ];
let table2Data = [ {name: 'ac', salary: 100}, {name: 'db', salary: 20} ];

// click event on search button
document.getElementById('search-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input').value;

    // filtered data which has matching
    let matchedData = [...table1Data, ...table2Data]
                        .filter(record => record.name === searchInput);
    /* 
       we can chain map function to the above statement
       for further extraction of only salary key from the filtered objects
    */
}
```